# Uncaught error upgrading Aurelia-router to 1.5

Tags: aurelia

I have used Microsoft Net Core SPA templates to produce a simple Aurelia application using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3) to produce a default installation. This builds and runs correctly. To upgrade the router to 1.5 followed the release notes (https://aurelia.io/blog/2018/01/22/big-changes-in-the-aurelia-router-150-release/) and issued the following NPM commands from a command window.

```
npm install aurelia-router@1.5 --save
npm install aurelia-history-browser@1.1 --save
npm install aurelia-bootstrapper@2.2 --save
```

When finished the application builds but gives the following error. I have tried using different versions of the npm packages but not found any that work at all. NOdeJS version is 8.9.4 and npm version is 4.6.1

> Uncaught (in promise TypeError:**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_aurelia_pal**.DOM.injectStyles is not a function

[image]

Comment: have you updated the autelia-pal package also? this could be the issue.

Comment: Please let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: No. This error occurred without updating anything else ;-)

Comment: After some hours experimentation it was found the following updates could get the page displaying though validation was broken where called got messages such as ERROR [app-router] Error: Expression 'title&validate' is not compatible with the validate binding-behavior.



npm install aurelia-pal-browser@1.2.1
npm install aurelia-templating-resources@1.4.0
npm install aurelia-templating-router@1.1.0

Comment: `Error: Expression 'title&validate' is not compatible with the validate binding-behavior.` shows up with `aurelia-binding` 2. try downgrading it back to 1.7

Comment: Thanks. However downgrading Aurelia-binding to 1.7.0 or 1.7.1 results in a TypeScript error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'getContextFor'. The referenced file I ..\dist\Aurelia-binding.d.ts. Anything else I can do?